# Angular ng-table loading from server with pagination

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to populate an ng-table and apply the total value for the params. It appears there are examples that are showing almost what I'm doing - but not exactly and the total never gets set.

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 25}, 
 {
   counts: [],
   getData: function(params)
   if (CompaniesView.ViewInitialized)
     return CompaniesView.RetrieveCompanies($scope, $http, function ()
     {
        params.total($scope.RequestFilter.TotalCompanies);
        return $scope.TableParams.data;
      });
  }
 });
```

My `RetrieveCompanies` function retrieves he data - and will call a callback function on completion. I was under the impression at this point I could set the `params.total`, but is not working. I see that examples are doing similar, except they are performing a jQuery API operation directly. I am not sure why this does not work. I would have thought anytime setting the total would cause the table pagination controls to update - but it appears it has to be done within the detData call. But if you are making an async call how can we have the total set in the call since it won't have data until the async completes - which means the 
getData call has already finished.

Probably missing some concept here -- but I am not an expert when it comes to jQuery or angular.

Peter

Update:

RetrieveCompanies function

```
RetrieveCompanies: function (scope, http,callback)
{
        scope.IsLoading = true;

        var Data =
        {
            AuthoirzationType: TokenRetrieval.SessionAuth,
            SessionId: activeSession
        };

        var tokenRequest =

        {
            params: Data
        };

        performVeilabilityTokenRetrieval(http, tokenRequest,
        function (response)
        {
            if (true)
            {
                if (!response.HasError)
                {
                    scope.RequestFilter.State = scope.selectedState.Value
                    scope.RequestFilter.regionsearch = scope.selectedRegion.id;
                    scope.RequestFilter.checkadminStaff = scope.selectedAdmin.value;

                    //tableParams
                    scope.RequestFilter.Page = scope.tableParams.page();
                    scope.RequestFilter.PageCount = scope.tableParams.count();

                    var config =
                    {
                        headers:
                        {
                            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + response.RequestToken
                        },
                        params: scope.RequestFilter
                    }

                    http.get(CompaniesView.Companies_api_urls.loadCompaniesRequest, config)
                    .then(                    
                        function (response)
                        {                            
                            scope.RequestFilter.TotalCompanies = response.data.companieslistTotal;
                            scope.TableParams.data = response.data.companies;
                            if (callback != null) callback();                            
                        },                    
                        function (data, status, headers, config) //error
                        {
                            scope.IsLoading = false;
                        }
                    );
               }
               else
               {
                    scope.request.requestToken = null;
                    //CreateExpenseView.PrepareRESTResults(data.RestResults);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                scope.request.requestToken = null;
                scope.request.error = data.replace(/\"/g, "");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you show  RetrieveCompanies function?

Answer (score 0):

Ok; finally found what was wrong. The ng-table getData operation requires a promise to be returned. My function was not configured as a deferred promise and once I realized this I put in place the required modification for my data retrieval to return a promise. One big point -- when I wrapped my call with a when - I completed with a done - and getData is operating off a then (from the promise). Once those changes were in place the pagination (total) operation worked.

Peter